# Save file outside the root directory vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net-2010

Hi I am developing web application in vb.net. I was facing problem while uploading my file from client side to the server side folder using this code

```
Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
Dim ext As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName)
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/EmployeeSignature/../../") + "IMG12345" & ext)
```

Here is root and target folders structure

[image]

Here is my site internal structure (UploadingTest)
[image]

Problem is that at this line

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/EmployeeSignature/../../") + "IMG12345" & ext)
```

I am getting error message

```
Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.
```

My requirement is to save file above the root directory , try alot but unable to solve problem , Kindly suggest any solution! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IIS, Add Virtual Directories inside you Website

1. EmployeeSignature
2. Images

Now you can access the folders using below code

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("EmployeeSignatures")
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Images")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `..` in the logical path to step outside the folder of your web root when you use `MapPath` to convert it. Move those outside the `MapPath` call:

```
Server.MapPath("~") + "\..\EmployeeSignature\IMG12345" + ext
```